# RMD conversion to PDF

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

I am trying to turn an RMD into a PDF, but keep getting this error

```
output file: hw1.knit.md

/Volumes/RStudio-0.99.893/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS hw1.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output hw1.tex --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.15.2.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine /Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
/Volumes/RStudio-0.99.893/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS hw1.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output hw1.pdf --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.15.2.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine /Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
! LaTeX Error: Command \end{enumerate} invalid in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.206 \end{enumerate}

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

If formats perfectly into an html, but i need a PDF. 
I have TeX, and have tried the various fixes I've seen on here, but nothing is working

Comment: You could use `keep_tex: true` to keep the intermediate tex file and check out what exactly happened in line 206...

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion that allowed me to solve a similar issue. In my case, I had written `$\equiv50%$` instead of `$\equiv50\%$` (missing backslash in front of `%`).

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate should be

`1. part of
2. a numbered list`

or

`* an un-
* ordered list`

can you post that part of your .Rmd ?